# mxGraph: loading XML file

Tags: xml, mxgraph, draw.io

I'm new to mxGraph. Does anyone know how to save a file to my local storage from mxGraph editor (http://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/grapheditor/www/index.html)?
BTW, are XML files created with draw.io compatible with mxGraph?
Thanks.

Comment: you can use this one https://www.draw.io for saving xml to local directory

Comment: That's obvious. What I'm asking is how to do the same with mxGraph, I mean saving the drawing XML to local storage.

Comment: Sorry @Jopa if im misunderstood. I have saved an XML from mxGraph and imported that XML in draw.io and it is imported correctly. but i have not tested the reverse yet.

Comment: @Shaybi how did you save the XML from mxGraph?

Comment: you can user Codec and Encoder to get this done.
    ` var encoder = new mxCodec();
 var node = encoder.encode(graph.getModel());
 mxUtils.popup(mxUtils.getPrettyXml(node), true);`

or just console the "node" which will contain xml.

Comment: It works @Shaybi. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Codec and Encoder.

```
var encoder = new mxCodec();
var node = encoder.encode(graph.getModel());
```

variable `node` will have XML of your graph.

Use mxGraph utility to instantly show XML in popup.

```
mxUtils.popup(mxUtils.getPrettyXml(node), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

"are XML files created with draw.io compatible with mxGraph". Yes they are. See my example at [mxGraph: Create graph with XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527357/mxgraph-create-graph-with-xml/63495413#63495413)